# GROUP BY using a SUM

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

This is a tough one to explain. I have this data set

**Data set 1**

```
counter | id
   1      280
   1      280
   0      280
   1      781
   1      781
   1      781
   0      25
   1      25
   1      25
```

I want to GROUP BY the id, but with the SUM of counter so I end up with this data set

**Data set 2**

```
counted | id
   2      280
   3      781
   2      25
```

I have tried a number of approaches but I always end up with the total SUM of rows for each ID like this

**Data set 3**

```
counted | id
   3      280
   3      781
   3      25
```

**EDIT**

It might be worth noting that **data set 1** comes from a sub query and is not a table in itself.

**EDIT**

I have used a query like this, it gives me the result of **data set 3**

```
select sum(counter) as counted, id
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: What query are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do this?

```
select sum(counter) as counted, id
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: I had! And it looked wrong. But the order of the `id` column in my data was not correct. So when looking at it it looked wrong, but looking all the data for an id showed that the SUM was in fact correct.